# need help in grouping the boxes according to their property values

Tags: c#

Here, a list has been created in which it stores length, height, depth of a box. now, i need to group the boxes which have equal length,height,depth and volume. i need to create groups in which it has boxes of equal length,height,depth except the bno(box number). kindly help me to solve this. @serv This is my actual code can u just change whereever its necessary.

```
    namespace ReadInputfromText
{
    class Box
    {
        private string bno;
        private double length;
        private double height;
        private double depth;
        private double volume;

        // Declare a number of box of type string:
        public string bnumber
        {
            get
            {
                return bno;
            }
            set
            {
                bno = value;
            }
        }

        // Declare  properties of box of type double:
        public double blength
        {
            get
            {
                return length;
            }
            set
            {
                length = value;
            }
        }
        public double bheight
        {
            get
            {
                return height;
            }
            set
            {
                height = value;
            }
        }
        public double bdepth
        {
            get
            {
                return depth;
            }
            set
            {
                depth = value;
            }
        }
        public double bvolume
        {
            get
            {
                return volume;
            }
            set
            {
                volume = value;
            }
        }

        public static void boxdetails(string[] args)
        {
            String line;
            List<Box> listofboxes = new List<Box>();
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:/containervalues.txt"))

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // create new instance of container for each line in file
                        Box box = new Box();
                      //  List<Box> listofboxes = new List<Box>();
                        string[] Parts = line.Split(' ');
                        // set non-static properties of container
                        box.bno = Parts[0];
                        box.length = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[1]);
                        box.height = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[2]);
                        box.depth = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[3]);
                        box.volume = Convert.ToDouble(Parts[4]);
                        // add container to list of containers
                        listofboxes.Add(box);

                    }
                listofboxes = listofboxes.OrderBy(x => x.volume).ToList();
                var groupedBoxes = listofboxes.GroupBy(b => new { b.depth, b.height, b.length }).Dump();
            }

            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                // FileNotFoundExceptions are handled here.
            }



    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this grouping: (I have scratched the code together in LinqPad)

```
void Main()
{
    var boxes = new List<Box>()
    {
      new Box(1, 2, 2, 2),
      new Box(2, 2, 2, 2),
      new Box(3, 3, 3, 3),
      new Box(4, 3, 3, 3),
      new Box(5, 4, 4, 4)
    };

    var groupedBoxes = boxes.GroupBy (b => new {b.depth, b.height, b.length}).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Box
{
  public Box(int bno, int len, int hei, int dep)
  {
    this.bno = bno; this.length = len; 
    this.height = hei; this.depth = dep; 
    //assuming volume is result of former 3 properties
    this.volume = length * depth * height;
  }


    public int bno { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int depth { get; set; }
    public int volume { get; set; }
}
```

**Output: (ignore the last line, where it is summed up, only in LinqPad)**

[image]

Comment: Hi serv. can u kindly have a look at this

Comment: Manju, your updated code looks fine. Just delete the `.Dump()`, which is not available in Visual Studio and it should work.

Comment: you might need to edit the grouping to blength, bdepth and bheigth. Because that are your public Box class properties.

Answer (score 0):

you could use linq and groupby, the length ,height and depth multiplied will give you the volume, so you would only need to group by volume.

therefore:

```
var groupedList = listofboxes.Groupby(item=> item.Volume);
```

Comment: Equal Volume, does not mean equal length of edges (height, depth, length)